# How to dump raw memory into a struct fast?

Tags: c, memory, uefi, gnu-efi

I'm in an identity-mapped memory context (UEFI on x86_64 platform) and I want to dump some contiguous memory content into a structure. Say my structure has this shape:

```
typedef struct _mystr {
    char char_arr[7];
    uint32_t u_d;
    uint8_t u_b;
} __attribute__((packed)) mystr;
```

Supposing I have in `mem_ptr` the address to the requested memory's offset 0, what's the best way to copy its content into a `mystr` instance? Is there a way to do that without iterating through memory with a loop (which seems super boring)?

---

**EDIT**: Nicolas Jean suggested the use of `memcpy` but unfortunately in an `EFI` developing context the use of a C standard library makes little sense. However, `efilib.h` from `gnu-efi` has **`CopyMem(IN VOID * dst, IN CONST VOID * src, IN UINTN len)`** which carries out the same task.

Comment: Isn't a sequence of repetitive assignments more boring than a loop? ;)

Comment: Not easy to do in a well-defined way in pure C and you've already sacrificed portability; suggest you use inline assembly.

Comment: You might have problems with data crossing word boundaries in your struct. Might cause crashes on some platforms.

Comment: @doron isn't __attribute__((packed)) there to prevent this kind of problems?

Comment: All packed says is that the struct does not have gaps inside. Accessing the data will depend on the platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying the memory content with memcpy is probably what you are looking for.

```
mystr mystr_instance;
memcpy(&mystr_instance, mem_ptr, sizeof(mystr_instance));
```

Comment: The question uses the `packed` attribute so it should work.

Comment: Marked as accepted, your answer solved my problem in a way (see edit).

Answer (score 2):

As you have correctly identified, memcpy does not really exist in the UEFI environment, but CopyMem works well if used for something compiled into the firmware image.

For drivers or applications, you'd be better off using the gBS->CopyMem() boot service.

Comment: Wow I didn't notice the boot service, thanks for pointing it out. What's the advantage of using BS->CopyMem over efilib's CopyMem for drivers and applications?

Comment: Well, for a start, in order to use CopyMem you would need to include BaseMemoryLib in your .efi to begin with, increasing the size. There is also the (more theoretical) aspect that the boot service could be more optimised for the platform being executed on.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the memory is in the correct format you can either cast a pointer to the address or memcpy the data into your struct